# ¿Cómo consultar en Oracle para saber el tamaño de los objetos por cada esquema?

Tags: oracle

Soy nuevo en oracle, los scripts que consigo en internet no me funcionan, es decir las vistas o tablas al cual hacen referencia no existen en la base de datos donde hago las consultas, ejemplo (`dba_objects`, `dba_segments`, etc).

Necesito una consulta donde me listen todos los esquemas con sus respectivos objetos, o mejor si éstas ya están sumadas (el tamaño de cada objeto)

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Las vistas `dba_objects`, `dba_segments`, etc... sí existen. deben existir. Es solo que aparentemente tu usuario no tiene los permisos necesarios para verlos. Necesitas ser un DBA para poder acceder a esa información.

Comment: Solo he podido consultar a `all_objects`, pero este no me sirve de mucho.

Comment: No hay otra. Para obtener la información que necesitas, tienes que usar un login de DBA. Si no, no se puede.

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente quien formuló esta pregunta ya descubrió como hacerlo, como quiera hago mi aportación por si a alguien mas le sirve.

Para poder leer el diccionario de datos necesitas que la cuenta de usuario tenga el privilegio **select any dictionary** o el rol **select_catalog_role**, de lo contrario solo podrás ver lo que te hayan dado permiso de ver.

Una vez que tengas el permiso o el rol podrás hacer consultas a vistas DBA%. El siguiente es un ejemplo ilustrativo, necesitarás adecuarlo a tus necesidades.

```
set linesize 150
col owner for a30
col segment_name for a35
select owner, segment_name, sum(bytes)/1048576 seg_size
  from dba_segments
 group by owner, segment_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu puedes utiliza el siguiente código para recuperar el tamaño por tabla en un esquema, para un tamaño total retira la condición que el objeto sea tabla

```
SELECT segment_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
SUM (BYTES) AS "[Bytes]",
SUM (BYTES) / 1024 AS "[Kb]",
SUM (BYTES) / (1024*1024) AS "[Mb]",
SUM (BYTES) / (1024*1024*1024) AS "[Gb]"
FROM user_segments
WHERE segment_type = 'TABLE'
GROUP BY segment_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el tamaño total de los objetos de cada esquema, la consulta es:

```
select owner, sum(bytes)
from dba_segments
group by owner
```

Pero, para poder usar la vista `dba_segments`, necesitas conectarte con un usuario que sea `DBA`.